# Running a C++ program in Windows vs Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compatibility

I've been told by my teacher that my homework (a simple program, I chose to code in C++) must be runnable in Linux. Here's what he said exactly:

"...you should also include a README file that contains all command lines that should run by
 cut-and-paste. If you used C, then

```
 $ gcc –o 2010-11649-hairpin 2010-11649-hairpin.c
 $ 2010-11649-hairpin –input filename –l 200 –m 4 –h 20
```

"

Where `-l 200`, `-m 4` and the like are parameters of the program.

I've always coded in Windows, and I have very little experience running programs from the command line, so I'm not sure what I need to do to make sure my program can run in Linux. Can someone help me figure out what I need to do? I've written the program, I just need to make sure everything works when the TA tries to run it in Linux.

Comment: If you just use standard c++ there's no need to worry about compatibility.

Comment: Well, if you want to be sure that TA will have the same result with you, then you need to test compilation on a similar environment to that of your TA's. Do you not have access to a Linux computer?

Comment: If your teacher told you you need to compile your programs in linux, but didn't show you at least an introductory course in using linux, then there is a problem and it is within your rights to politely ask him for instructions on how to do that

Comment: Install VirtualBox on your Windows machine and put Linux on it, then you'll be set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you will have to try this by executing your instructions on Linux.

If you have written your program in standard C/C++ it will compile and then run on Linux just fine. Once you get to the less basic parts, you have big chances you have used OS specific headers and it might not work as easily.

When compiling a C++ program under Linux, normally you want to use `g++` the C++ compiler in `gcc`. Depending on your program, replacing `gcc` with `g++` in your example might work (although your filenames probably are different).
So you might end up with something like:

```
g++ –o myprogram myprogram.cpp
./myprogram –l 200 –m 4
```

The above will only work for basic programs with all source code in a single directory.

Comment: I have some helper functions that I need to compile too. If `myProgram` relies on the helper function, say, `Helper()`that in written a seperate .cpp file, what is the procedure for getting `myProgram` working through the terminal?

Comment: You can just add other source files after the first source file. So you could do `g++ –o myprogram myprogram.cpp helper.cpp`. The second command `./myprogram` will run the program from a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

One fast way to see that your program compiles in gcc is to use an online compiler like [ideone](http://ideone.com/). Paste you code there and select C++ 4.9.whateverversion (**gcc**) and then compile and run.

The alternative is to install a linux OS, easiest and most convenient way in a virtual machine. You can use the free [oracle virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation).

Setting up linux in a vm is [easy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

There are other answers here showing you how to compile your program from command line in linux.

Answer (score 2):

If your C++ program uses also just one file (e.g. hairpin.cpp), you could use almost the exact same commands, except that you replace `gcc` by `g++` and `hairpin.c`by `hairpin.cpp`.

However, if you've got enough time and system resources, I would recommend you try compiling and running everything in a virtual machine. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
 is a good and free virtualization software, and [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) is in my opinion a very beginner-friendly distribution.

Testing everything yourself on a VM is probably the best solution to ensure everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I stay corrected here: As @Thirler posted in another answer, it would also work with more source files, but all in a single directory.